# Combine columns in result from SQL SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to solve following problem:

I have a table with timeStamp column and three columns for different types of variables. The columns with values are filled randomly according to the conditions. So it looks like this:

> smpl_time   float_val   num_val   str_val 
> 15:31
>           10            NULL      NULL
>   
> 15:32         NULL       15.4        NULL
>   
> 15:33        
>   NULL        NULL      Disabled

What I would like to achieve is a result that would merge all val fields into one column and sorts them according to timeStamp:

> smpl_time  merge_val
>   
> 15:31        10
>   
> 15:32        15.4
>   
> 15:33        Disabled

So far I have a SELECT just for one val type looking like this (it contains also other field from the table that are common for each entry):

```
SELECT s.smpl_time AS Time,s.float_val AS Value, e.name AS Severity, m.name AS Status 
FROM sample s JOIN channel c ON c.channel_id=s.channel_id JOIN severity e ON
e.severity_id=s.severity_id JOIN status m ON m.status_id=s.status_id WHERE
s.channel_id='id' AND smpl_time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP 'startTime' AND TIMESTAMP 'stopTime';
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this or if it is even possible?

Cheers,

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming only one of the three columns is populated for any given row, use the [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function.

```
SELECT smpl_time, COALESCE(float_vaL, num_val, str_val) AS merge_val
    FROM ...
```

Comment: IIRC If the 1st row resulted in an int and the 2nd in a char type you would need a cast to a type that supported both (eg char)

Answer (score 2):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

COALESCE(value,...)

**Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.**

mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULL,1);
        -> 1

mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULL,NULL,NULL);
        -> NULL